# Visual Studio 2008 doesn't connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

When i try to establish a connection with SQL Server 2008 i am getting:

> The server version is not supported. only servers up to SQL Server 2005 are supported.

What's wrong with this? is there a patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 came out in 2007, while SQL Server 2008 wasn't released until Late 2008. So although they have the same year in the names, there is a pretty big gap between them.

The current solution is to upgrade to Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1

SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Comment: thanks. i have visual studio 2008 professional. is that previous to the SP1?

Comment: Yes, 'professional' is just the edition of Visual Studio that you have.

Comment: @jenny - select the 'Help' menu and look at 'About Microsoft Visual Studio' - if it does not say you are on SP1 (check the Visual Studio not the .Net Framework data), you can get the download at MSDN here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en